# Iterator and printing details

Tags: java

Hey all. I've been asked to create a method that uses an iterator to print details of 'lots'. I'm able to create an iterator that prints all of the details, however, for any lots that haven't been bought, a message should print out this fact and I'm unsure how I can add that code in. It is the public void close method I'm focusing on. This is what I have so far. Help is greatly appreciated.

```
public class Auction{

    // The list of Lots in this auction.
    private final ArrayList<Lot> lots;
    // The number that will be given to the next lot entered
    // into this auction.
    private int nextLotNumber;

    /**
     * Create a new auction.
     */
    public Auction(){
        lots = new ArrayList<Lot>();
        nextLotNumber = 1;
    }

    /**
     * Enter a new lot into the auction.
     * 
     * @param description
     *            A description of the lot.
     */
    public void enterLot(final String description){
        lots.add(new Lot(nextLotNumber, description));
        nextLotNumber++;
    }

    /**
     * Show the full list of lots in this auction.
     */
    public void showLots(){
        for(final Lot lot : lots){
            System.out.println(lot.toString());
        }
    }

    public void close(){
        final Iterator<Lot> it = lots.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){

        }
    }

    /**
     * Bid for a lot. A message indicating whether the bid is
     * successful or not is printed.
     * 
     * @param number
     *            The lot number being bid for.
     * @param bidder
     *            The person bidding for the lot.
     * @param value
     *            The value of the bid.
     */
    public void bidFor(final int lotNumber,
        final Person bidder,
        final long value){
        final Lot selectedLot = getLot(lotNumber);
        if(selectedLot != null){
            final boolean successful =
                selectedLot.bidFor(new Bid(bidder, value));
            if(successful){
                System.out.println("The bid for lot number " + lotNumber
                    + " was successful.");
            } else{
                // Report which bid is higher.
                final Bid highestBid = selectedLot.getHighestBid();
                System.out.println("Lot number: " + lotNumber
                    + " already has a bid of: " + highestBid.getValue());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide more details on the full `Lot` API?

Answer (score 2):

Does the Lot class have a flag indicating if it's purchased or not?  If so then

```
for(final Lot lot : lots){
   if (!lot.purchased) {
     System.out.println("not bought");
   }
}
```

BTW - I noticed you're using the pre for-each style iterator in the close method. There's no reason to do this since you'll have access to individual Lot instances in the for-each also.

Comment: purchased should be a method not a field so the if should read

Answer (score 0):

I would add the information you want the Lot to print to the Lot.toString() I would suggest your close() method should close() each lot, and the lot should print anything which needs to be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Add an attribute to the Lot class of type Person called "winner" or something similar.

In the bidFor method, in the if (successful) block, set the winner attribute:

```
selectedLot.setWinner(bidder);
```

Then when iterating through the lots, if the winner attribute is null, print your message that the lot hasn't been bought.

Or you could use:

```
if (lot.getHighestBid() == null)
```

depending on how the Lot class is implemented, hard to know without seeing the Lot class.